# Is docker0 virtual bridge or virtual interface

Tags: networking, docker

Some articles define docker0 bridge as virtual bridge, but another as virtual interface. 1. So if this any network bridge (bridge is L2 device by default), why it has IP address? 2. So what is it exactly docker0 bridge? Can you define me a native definition of docker0 bridge in Linux world? What docker0 consist of?

Answer (score 1):

It's always **both things at once.**

In Linux, you cannot actually create a "detached" bridge. You always start by creating a virtual `bridge` interface, and it simultaneously creates a L2 bridge and attaches one of its ports to the interface you just created.

So the interface has an IP address because it represents the host OS connection to this bridge (just like eth0 would have an IP address because it represents the connection to a physical switch). Note that it doesn't *need* an IP address for bridging to work – the IP address is strictly for allowing the host *itself* participate in the network.

However, all of bridge management commands use the same interface to represent the actual L2 bridge, too. For example, if you want to list member ports or set up VLANs, you refer to the bridge as "docker0" and the OS understands it as "the virtual bridge that docker0 connects to".